# Why does the Django 'PostgreSQL Full Text Search' not return my objects and how to fix it?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search, django-postgresql

I can't get the [PostgreSQL Full Text Search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) feature to work as I need it.

I have a model `Verein`with a field `straße`. There are two `Verein` objects where `straße` has the value *"Uhlandstraße"*.

What I want to achieve is that a search for "Uhl", "uhl", "nds", "straße" or "andstr" (you get the idea) returns those objects. Instead it does this:

```py
>>> # With missing only 1 char at the end of the word, the search works.
>>> Verein.objects.filter(straße__search='Uhlandstraß')
<QuerySet [<Verein: 1>, <Verein: 2>]>

>>> # With missing more than 1 char at the and of the word, the search does not work.
>>> Verein.objects.filter(straße__search='Uhl')
<QuerySet []>
>>> Verein.objects.filter(straße__search='Uhlandstra')
<QuerySet []>

>>> # Same amount of chars as the working example, but from the end of the word, it does not work
>>> Verein.objects.filter(straße__search='hlandstraße')
<QuerySet []>
```

Any ideas what I need to change to get it working like explained?

Comment: FTS does not shine with compound words. And it is never designed to find matches by part of the words (i.e. by just a few characters). FTS will only find matches when there are matching [lexemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme). F.ex. the document `Uhlandstraße` is a match with a `uhlandstrasse` query (in the `german` configuration). -- If you want to search by only parts of some words, you should use e.g. `col ILIKE '%uhl%'`

Comment: @pozs, the thing is, I want to be able to search all fields of my model later on. I was just testing the feature using the easiest approach.